# Laravel 5: DOMPDF(0.8.3) set margin-top in each page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dompdf, export-to-pdf

I am using dompdf version 0.8.3 in all our reports, we have done the adding header and footer in each page. Now we want to have margin-top in each page of our header because our header overlapped to our table.

**PDF**

```
<script type="text/php">
        if (isset($pdf)) {
            $x = 550;
            $y = 800;
            $text = "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}";
            $font = null;
            $size = 12;
            $color = array(255,0,0);
            $word_space = 0.0;  //  default
            $char_space = 0.0;  //  default
            $angle = 0.0;   //  default
            // header
            $pdf->page_text(550,10,'P O #: <?= $purchase_order->number ?>',$font,$size,$color,$word_space,$char_space,$angle);
            // footer
            $pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color, $word_space, $char_space, $angle);
        }
    </script>
```

**Controller**

```
<!-- My other function/data -->
$pdf = PDF::loadView('purchase-order.export.export-pdf', $data)->setPaper('a4');
$pdf->getDomPDF()->set_option("enable_php", true);
return $pdf->stream('purchase-order-'.$purchase_order->number.'.pdf');
```

Question: Is it possible to have a margins(margin-top to be specific in each page) and to skip the 1st page to have header and page number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your pdf blade file, you can use css styles. For margins, try this something like this, and edit numbers for your preference:

```
<style>
    @page  {
        margin: 2cm 2cm 1.5cm 1.5cm;
    }

</style>
```

As for page brakes, I'm not sure exactly what do you want to achieve, but you can add page breaks inside the same pdf blade like this:

```
<div class="page-break"></div>
```

Hope that this can lead you in right direction.

Comment: Is it possible to skip the page number in the 1st page? It will appear on the 2nd page onwards.

Comment: For that, you should make another question, and provide all the code you have by now.

Comment: Hello sir can you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57659097/dompdf0-8-3-skip-the-1st-page-having-header.